# Swift exception details

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm using Swift exceptions in Swift 2. I'm using the NSFileHandle(forWritingToURL) constructor, which is failing.

I've got the error in my `catch` block, but all XCode will tell me about it is that it's an ErrorType, which is maximally unhelpful. I can't even seem to NSLog it.

How the hell do I figure out what's the problem?

Comment: Have you tried using `Mirror(reflecting: ...)` to introspect the error?

Comment: They are not exceptions, they are just error handling.

Comment: Did you have a look at the "Error Handling" and "Catching and Handling an Error" sections in the "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" book? There are code samples including error logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for some reason your error in `catch` does not behave as expected, try casting it as an NSError and inspect its `debugDescription` property:

```
do {
    try NSFileHandle(forWritingToURL: ...)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.debugDescription)
}
```

ErrorType is bridged to NSError so with this syntax it should tell you the usual error domain, error code and error message.

Answer (score 0):

If its a method created by Apple it is very likely that it is actually returning an NSError and not an ErrorType... yet.

In the catch you can cast the ErrorType to NSError.

```
catch let error as NSError
```

And then do like you did before Swift 2.